# Multiple one-to-one relationships in one entity

Tags: database

I'm designing a database for my game, and I've stumbled upon a small uncertainty.

My character should have two item containers - one for inventory and another one for items that are equipped.

I was wondering whether my solution is considered a bad practice and I should create another table called "character_container"?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just have one inventory (Map) and each item has a boolena attribute "waering"?

Comment: If both containers have the same attributes and you don't ever plan on scaling them differently, your design is fine.  If however, you expect them to diverge in attributes, a separate table is warranted.

Comment: Looking at your tables, its the wrong way round. Table "container" must have a reference to the "game_character", so you can have many items in container which belong to the character.

Comment: @Hajo Boolean attribute on items might cause new problems, because each wearable item when equipped is not exactly in the inventory. About container having a reference to "game_character", that won't work, but as you can see, "user" has a reference to container (acting like a global container or a storage).

Answer (score 1):

You have a user which can have multiple game_characters. So in DB you need a table game_character with a column "user_ref char(36) referencing user ( id )". Same goes for your inventory: In the DB you need a table "item" (or "container") with a reference to the game character: "game_char_ref char(36) referencing game_character ( id )".
In Java its the other way round. You have a user with a collection of game_characters and a game_character with a collection of items.
In a proper design, I suggest one table "Item" which contains all available items in the game with their attributes and one linking table "item4character" assigning an item to a game_character with count and attribute if its in the inventory, chest or worn.